# Using Data Extension to exclude subscribers from Journey Builder sent Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder

Is there a way to use Data Extension instead of suppression list in a mail being sent out of Journey Builder for excluding the subscribers. Currently I do not see any option of using Data Extension for excluding the subscribers [Refer to the screenshot below].

Domain suppression do refer to DataExtension but we need the same functionality for excluding the subscribers . This is required because we already have DataExtension in placed with excluded subscriber. We just want to use the same functionality in JB send mails too

[image: Exclude subscribers from JB mails]

Also is there a way to import the records from the existing DataExtension to subscriber list? In case we go ahead with the subscriber list option we can easily import the data from our existing DataExtension to Subscriber list. TIA

Comment: Please can you confirm if (a) you want to suppress specific subscribers from entering the Interaction or (b) you want them to enter the Interaction, but just bypass any Send Email activities within the Interaction for subscribers that appear in the Data Extension?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who had issues similar to mine (I'm relatively new to AMPscript), the suggested solution did not work for me as we typically call SubscriberKey in data extensions "ContactID". Also, the ">1" didn't filter for me, but using ">0" did. So what worked for me was:

```
rowcount(lookuprows("EXCLUSIONDE", "ContactID", _subscriberkey)) > 0
```

If your data extension calls Subscriber Key something different, make sure to indicate that. Also, it didn't work as "Contact ID" with the space - it only worked once I changed it to "ContactID", so make sure whatever you call it has no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an Exclusion Script:

```
rowcount(lookuprows("EXCLUSIONDE", "SubscriberKey", _subscriberkey)) > 1
```

There are plenty of other examples here on SFSE if you'd look around a little:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bampscript%5D+exclusion+script

Comment: is there a way to implement it Out of Box, through standard way(no through customization script etc) also is there a way to import the records from the existing DataExtension to subscriber list? In case we go ahead with the subscriber list option we can easily import the data from our existing DataExtension to Subscriber list

Comment: This script goes in the Exclusion Script input box in the screenshot in your question.

Comment: Did this work for you?  I so, would you checking the check-mark beside my answer?  I'd appreciate it.  For more information about accepting answers, take a look at our [FAQ](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).